# press "q" to exit the program

Tags: python, string, input

when i press q, i get an error. i know whats wrong but i dont know what will i do. im at the beginnig of programming, thanks already

```
while True:
   ilk_sayi = input("ilk sayi (press q to exit): ")

   if ilk_sayi == "q":
       break

   ikinci_sayi = input("ikinci sayı: ")

   try:
       sayı1 = int(ilk_sayi)
       sayı2 = int(ikinci_sayi)
       print(sayi1, "/", sayi2, "=", sayi1 / sayi2)
   except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
       print("Bir hata olustu!")
       print("Lutfen tekrar deneyin!")
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Side note: `sayı1` is not the same as `sayi1`.

Comment: (NameError: name 'q' is not defined) So if i want to quit, i must write "q", not q. But i wanna write only q. What am i gonna do?

Comment: it does not matter, im Turkish. I just fix them to understand easily, i haven't seen that :) forget it, problem is pressing q

Comment: Briefly: you're running that in Python 2. Use `raw_input` instead of `input`, or run it with Python 3. I'd recommend using Python 3, because then the division will produce the result you expect.